# Auto-assign class to a new element (using parent)

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm creating very basic framework for adding elements to DOM with javascript, so I have this for the start:

```
function newElement(tag, id, className, innerHtml) {}
```

All was fine, until className attributes became too repetitive and cluttering, also I need certain classes at certain positions. So I basically want to auto-assign CSS classes to my elements. I think of having Map object, with keys of class/id, and values as strings/arrays, so I end up like this:

```
function newElement(parent, tag, id, innerHtml) {
  var e = document.createElement(tag);
  var testedAttributes = [parent.id, parent.className, id];
  for (var key of testedAttributes) {
    if app.classMap.has(key) {
      //check if app.classMap.get(key) is array
      //assign className by index
      //else assign by value
    }
  ..
  return e;
}
```

Is this alright, or I should take a better way for adding elements ?
Like, evaluate classes on adding (event) ?

Comment: Looks like you need to use a Factory or even better, an abstract Factory:
https://anasshekhamis.com/2017/08/10/the-factory-design-pattern-in-javascript/

Comment: Use JQuery it is fun!

Comment: @CharybdeBE, no! App will have no dependencies ;]

Comment: @NullPointer, I had read about factories, but have no idea on how to implement the pattern

Comment: `innerHTML`? Don't do that. Accept an array of child elements or texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix the utility function for creating elements with your application logic that puts classes on certain things. I would instead recommend to write an `add` function for each of your parent elements, and put the expected classes on the otherwise normally created elements before appending them to the DOM in a particular place.

```
function newElement(tag, attributes, children) { … }

function addItem(element) {
     element.classList.add("item");
     app.itemParent.appendChild(element);
}
```

Comment: So I should have object with documentFragment and methods like `append`, `evaluateClasses`, and `insertTo` ?

Comment: @DensiTensy Whether you need a fragment or not I don't know. `appendX` and `insertXTo` are dual, one of them should suffice, but if you like to go for a full OOP wrapper like jQuery then you might want to have both. I meant that you don't need `evaluateClasses`, I would recommend multiple "template" functions which each construct a part of your DOM - they should use `newElement` as a building block and add the relevant classes.

Comment: Ugh, I don't think this answers my need, but I'll give it a second thought.